# What are some ways to combine a number of (potentially incompatible) sorted sub-sets of a total set into a (partial) ordering of the total set?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a sorting problem that I'm pretty sure doesn't have a canonical "answer" - but probably has a number of different approaches, each with pros/cons. I'm interested in hearing some different approaches.

Suppose a bunch of people `{p_i | i=1,...,M}` are ranking their favorite ice cream flavors. In total there are `N` different flavors, but a single person `p_i` only ranks the `n_i << N` flavors that he or she is most familiar with. I'm interested in combining these sub-rankings into a plausible overall ranking of all `N` flavors.

For a concrete situation: my `M` and `N` are both roughly `1000` (by coincidence), and each `n_i` is about `20`. You can assume there's enough overlap in the flavors people rank such that no flavor is completely "isolated".

Again, I'm interested in hearing different ways to approach this, even if there isn't a single clear answer. Thanks!

Comment: And what exactly is you goal? BTW: it looks like a sparse N*M matrix in which you want to find the eigenvectors+ values. Look for "shopping cart", "PageRank", "power iteration" BTW: (partial) order may not be possible, because `a < b && b < c && c <a` can be  present.

Comment: I think you should read about *voting* as studied in game theory (in case you didn't yet). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_system for instance. One thing you can be sure about is that there is no *perfect* final ranking: Arrows impossibility theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem) shows that no ranking will satisfy a certain list of very natural requirements.

Comment: @wildplasser: The goal is somewhat vague, but a "plausible, closest-to-consensus" overall sorting is what I'm after. If the only votes were of the form `a < b && b < c && c <a`, then I'd think the only "plausible" answer would be ` a = b = c`.

Comment: @Heuster: With voting systems, the main problem I've found is that most systems assume (implicitly or explicitly) that each voter has an opinion about each candidate - but, in my situation, most voters aren't even familiar with the vast majority of candidates (flavors).

Comment: The same sparcity can be found in both Pagerank and the netflix-challenge (which was solved by an enhanced form of SVD)

Comment: This is not a real question for SO.  Real questions have a correct answer which can be determined.  By your own description, this does not, but is merely an invitation to suggest and discuss.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this problem would be to construct a directed a cyclic graph representing all of the constraints on the ordering of the elements. The nodes in the graph would represent the different elements to be compared and you would have an edge from a first node  a second node if someone had ranked the first element has better than the second element.  This graph would not be too large and can be constructed in linear time by creating one node for every. object and then adding edges based on the preferences.

There are two possibilities for this graph.  First, if the graph contains a cycle, there must be a conflict in the preferences and there's no way to order the elements consistently. Second, if the graph has no cycles, then any topological ordering of the graph will give an overall consistent ordering of the elements, since every element will be placed after all elements that transitively come before it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is too open ended for SO but I would suggest a simple yet effective weighted ranking and summing after.

I'm this method the persons will rank their choices from 1 to 20 where 1 is their favourite and carriers a weight of 20 and 20 being their worst with a weighting of 1.

Once all the preferences are in sum all the weights and you have you ranking.